# How to mount a windows folder in docker container?

Tags: docker

On my windows notebook I try to share a folder with my docker container, but I am getting a weird error message that does not tell me anything.

```
docker run -p 9999:9999 -it msmint/msmint:latest  -v c:/Users/swacker/MINT:/data/
```

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "-v": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

The `/data` folder in the docker file is present and I gried different formats for the windows path such as `C:\User\swacker\MINT`.

It complains that an executable file is not found, but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 2):

Options for docker need to go *before* the image name. Anything after the image name is a command for the container and replaces any defined `CMD` in the image.

So you need to do

```
docker run -p 9999:9999 -it -v c:\Users\swacker\MINT:/data/ msmint/msmint:latest
```

I've changed the slashes in your Windows path to backslashes.

Comment: Is this for a Windows machine or Linux machine?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen It's for a Windows machine. It'll be similar for Linux, but you have to use a Linux path instead of `c:\Users\swacker\MINT`. The path has to be absolute, so you can't use relative paths like `.`.